# Issue with SQL query and having correct format for created_at

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to craft my own SQL query in a Rails project, and no matter what I try I keep getting a complain on the format of the created_at.

```
current_time = Time.current
values = attribute_values.map { |attribute| "(#{current_item.id},#{attribute},#{current_time},#{current_time})" }.join(',')
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO line_item_attributes (line_item_id, product_attribute_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{values}")
```

returns the error:

```
PG::SyntaxError - ERROR:  syntax error at or near "18"
```

the SQL query in rails logs looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO line_item_attributes (line_item_id, product_attribute_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (76,12398,2016-07-13 18:35:30 +0200,2016-07-13 18:35:30 +0200),(76,12394,2016-07-13 18:35:30 +0200,2016-07-13 18:35:30 +0200)
```

how can I get the right format for this to save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `TIMESTAMP` here to clean up your import. Get Rails to give you a variable like `currentTime = Time.now` then use `values = attribute_values.map { |attribute| "(#{current_item.id},#{attribute},TIMESTAMP '#{currentTime}', TIMESTAMP'#{currentTime}')" }.join(',')`